# Hiding Module name in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I just created a ZF2 application from Zend Skeleton Application. The default routing of the skeleton needs the Module name in the URL. For example, to invoke **index** action in **index** controller in **application** module, i have to type the url like `http://localhost/application/index/index`.

i want to omit the module name from the url (*because i will only need one module for what i have in mind*) so that if i type `http://localhost/index/index`, i would get the same result.

i tried changing the default [module.config.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L27) file in application/config like this -

```
<?php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(   
                                'action' => 'index',
                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller'                             
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),            
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Home' => 'Application\Controller\HomeController',
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

but it's not working. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the slash from your child route. That is, `/[:controller[/:action]]` should be `[:controller[/:action]]`. Then it should work.

If you are interested in a walkthrough of the solution, I wrote [an article](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/removing-module-from-url-in-zend-framework-2) about it some months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I do the trick with this route definition in module.config.php:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'application' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action]][/]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),  
            ),
        ), 
    ),
),
```

With this line only use controller and action name without module

```
'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action]][/]'
```